# Filtering using lodash

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, lodash

I'm currently trying to perform a filter on a list of tests that are of a type ITests. I am using lodash to perform the filtering because someone recommended it to perform this task. What my goal is once I select a test, the test will filter and show it's respective questions. The current filter I have now, I know does not work, I've tried many different variations but can't seem to get the right filter. Any help is greatly appreciated. I hope my questions is concise and makes sense with the provided snippets as well.

Below are snippets of my code:

This is code in my listGroup where I try to filter the questions based on the selectedTests. The common entry I try to look for its moduleName as both test and questions share.

This is inside my ListGroup.tsx the filtering is done here.

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  UpdateSelectedTestType,
  UpdateSelectedTest
} from "../actions/TestActions";
import { ITestState } from "../models/ITestState";
import * as _ from "lodash";
interface IProps {
  onUpdatetoggleTestState: typeof UpdateSelectedTestType;
  toggleTestState: ITestState;
  onUpdateSelectedTest: typeof UpdateSelectedTest;
}
export class ListGroup extends React.Component<IProps> {
  public render() {
    let question = null
    if(this.props.toggleTesttate.selectedTest !=  undefined)
      var selectedtest = this.props.toggleTestState.selectedTest.moduleName
      questions = this.props.toggleTestState.questions
      var filterquestions = _.filter(questions, function(o){
        return _.isMatch(o, selectedtest )
      })
     console.log(filterquestion)
    return (
    );
  }
}
```

This is my toggleButtonReducer.ts

```
const initialState: ITestState = {
  testype: TestType.test1,
  tests: dbTest,
  questions: dbQuestions,
  selectedTest: undefined
  //selectedQuestion: undefined
};
```

The tests and questions share a common entry called moduleName so therefore I will be using this field to access the filtered questions based on the selected test.

This is my testActions.ts

```
export interface ITest {
  name: string;
  moduleName: string;
  testType: TestType


 export interface ITest {
      name: string;
      moduleName: string;
```

Comment: `_.filter(wedge,)` with `wedge = null` and never reassigned to anything else will not do anything.

Comment: What is `wedge`? You define it to be null then try to filter on it. Did you intend to actually filter `questions`?

Comment: That was a typo: I updated @DrewReese

Comment: Is there a property within each `question` that can match a property within `selectedtest` instead of testing deep equality, like an ID? What you have doesn't look wrong, but perhaps it just isn't the right test for filtering.

Comment: No there's no id: The only thing that makes tests and questions related is the moduleName

Comment: I'm not sure I worded this question properly or provided enough code @DrewReese

Comment: You are running `isMatch` on a question and (what looks to me) a primitive string. `isMatch` checks if two objects seem equal. I'm not sure what the intention is here - check a property from the question? Check if the question, which is a string, is equal to another string?

Comment: @user11996757 No, I saw your interfaces after I asked and saw they both have the `moduleName` property in common.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm trying to check if the question.modulename is contained in the selectedTest? I figured isMatch would do the trick, I guess not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript has built-in array filtering now that may have an easier API. It takes a callback that has the element, index, and original array passed to it and you can take as many of them as needed.

[edit] Added check if selectedTest is an array of module names

```
let selectedtest = this.props.toggleTestState.selectedTest.moduleName
let questions = this.props.toggleTestState.questions
let filteredQuestions = questions.filter(
  question => {
    if (Array.isArray(selectedTest) {
      return selectedTest.includes(question.moduleName);
    } else {
      return question.moduleName === selectedTest;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Yeah for some reason I get this error `"This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'string[]' have no overlap."`. I also forgot to mention that some Tests have a list  of modules associated with it. Not sure if that matters

Comment: Yeah, it does matter, but that can be accounted for in the filter function.